# Pipenv Install in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, pipenv, amazon-efs

I am attempting to run the Algolia Docsearch scraper in a lambda environment at set intervals. Described [here](https://docsearch.algolia.com/docs/legacy/run-your-own/). I've got the docker container uploaded to ECR and attached to a lambda function, but when I run it the lambda errors because the entrypoint of the container is `pipenv run python -m src.index`. Pipenv is attempting to create a directory `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'`.

To combat this I created a EFS with an access point that the lambda has access to. The issue is the volume gets mounted at `/mnt/...` which is not where pipenv is trying to write. I'm a bit stuck here. Is there a clever way to get pipenv pointed at the EFS mount point?